# how to arrange dots from seaborn swarmplot and respective boxplot, after grouping

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot, swarmplot

Does anyone know of a way to place the dots of grouped swarmplots, on their respective boxplot?
As it is right now, the **grouping causes the dots to appear on the midline of the two groups** (see attached image).

**Code:**

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(15.7,8.27)})
ax = sns.boxplot(data=mice_20191203, x="group", y="engraft", showfliers = False, hue="status")
ax = sns.swarmplot(data=mice_20191203, x="group", y="engraft", color=".25", size=6)

ax.set_title(label='K562 cells in NSG mice', fontsize=20)
ax.set_xlabel(xlabel='injected cells', fontsize=16)
ax.set_ylabel(ylabel='human CD45 (%)', fontsize=16)
plt.xticks(rotation=30)

plt.show()
```

**Output:**
[image: grouped boxplot and swarmplot]

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: Did you forget to use the `hue` argument in the swarmplot?

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Yes I did forget. But I tried adding it just now and it doesn't seem to have any effect, other than adding the names of the dots to the legend as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to using `hue=`, you have to use `dodge=True` in the call to `swarmplot`. See [the documentation for swarmplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html?highlight=swarmplot#seaborn.swarmplot).